# Calculate probability from a given quantile

Tags: r, statistics

Given a set of real numbers stored in a data frame `df` under a column `A`, and an element `r` in this set, how would you solve the following 'equation' for `q`:

`r = quantile(df$A, q)`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate the probability for a given quantile in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123800/how-do-i-calculate-the-probability-for-a-given-quantile-in-r)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `?quantile` we can read

> See Also
>
> ecdf for empirical distributions of which quantile is an inverse

Thus:

```
x <- rnorm(100)

r <- quantile(x, 0.05)
#       5% 
#-1.469996 

Fn <- ecdf(x)
Fn(r)
#[1] 0.05
```

Comment: If you're just running a quick check, you can do it in one line, as `ecdf(x)(r)`.